# Cannot invoke" 'setViewController' with an argument list of type [AnyObject]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

"Cannot invoke" 'setViewController' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection, animated: Bool, completion: nil)'"

I got this error in Xcode 7 beta 3 at this line of code:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
pageImages = NSArray(objects:"screenshot01","screenshot02","screenshot03")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var initialContenViewController = self.pageTutorialAtIndex(0) as TutorialPageContentHolderViewController

        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: initialContenViewController)


        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

I don't get the error if I run the same code in Xcode 6 and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature looks like:

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?,
              direction direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection,
               animated animated: Bool,
             completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

So why are you casting to `[AnyObject]`?

Try

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Depending on the type of `viewControllers` you might also need to use `as!`

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now with `as!` and `[UIViewController]`but I still get a warning "Treating a forced downcast to '[UIViewController]' as optional will never produce 'nil'. Just out of curiosity, why does did error show only in Xcode 7 and not in Xcode 6? Thank you again idmean!

Comment: @DavideNastasi It is trying to tell you that `as!` will crash the program if `viewControllers` does contain something that is not a `UIViewController`, for instance a `String`, and it recommends you to use `as?` instead because that would return `nil` if the array could not be casted to `[UIViewController]` and `setViewControllers` would accept `nil`. You have to decide whether the program should crash if there is something in the array that does not belong in it or whether it is ok to pass nil to `setViewControllers`.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode7.0, you may change it to

```
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```